# Adding multiple columns to Spark Dataset while iterating its records

Tags: apache-spark

Spark 2.1.x here. I have a bunch of JSON files (with identical schema) that I'm reading into a single Spark `Dataset` like so:

```
val ds = spark.read.json("some/path/to/lots/of/json/*.json")
```

I can then print the `ds` schema and see that everything has been read correctly:

```
ds.printSchema()

// Outputs:
root
 |-- fizz: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- moniker: string (nullable = true)
 |-- buzz: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
```

Please note the `moniker` string column. I would now like to:

1. Add three new columns to this dataset and/or its schema; (a) a date/time column called `special_date`, (b) a UUID column called `special_uuid` and (c) a string column called `special_phrase`; then
2. I need to iterate over all the records in `ds`, and for each record, pass its `moniker` value into three subsequent functions: (a) `deriveSpecialDate(val moniker : String) : Date`, (b) `deriveSpecialUuid(val moniker : String) : UUID` and (c) `deriveSpecialPhrase(val moniker : String) : String`. The output of each of these functions then needs to become that record's value for the respective column.

My best attempt:

```
val ds = spark.read.json("some/path/to/lots/of/json/*.json")

ds.foreach(record => {
  val moniker : String = record.select("moniker")
  val specialDate : Date = deriveSpecialDate(moniker)
  val specialUuid : UUID = deriveSpecialUuid(moniker)
  val specialPhrase : String = deriveSpecialPhrase(moniker)

  // This doesn't work because special_* fields don't exist in the original
  // schema dervied from the JSON files. We're ADDING these columns after the
  // JSON read and then populating their values dynamically.
  record.special_date = specialDate
  record.special_uuid = specialUuid
  record.special_phrase = specialPhrase
})
```

**Any idea how this can be accomplished?**

Comment: So basically you want to add three column by calling each function ?\

Comment: Hi @ShankarKoirala (+1) - yes exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would enhance the original dataset with 3 columns using udf (user defined functions) from spark

```
val deriveSpecialDate = udf((moniker: String) => // implement here)
val deriveSpecialUuid= udf((moniker: String) => // implement here)
val deriveSpecialPhrase = udf((moniker: String) => // implement here)
```

After that you can do something like this:

```
ds.withColumn("special_date", deriveSpecialDate(col("moniker)))
.withColumn("special_uuid", deriveSpecialUuid(col("moniker)))
.withColumn("special_phrase", deriveSpecialPhrase (col("moniker)))
```

It will bring you a new dataframe with the three columns. If you want you can also convert in into a dataset by using the map function

Comment: Thanks @dumitru (+1) - will this solution (`ds.withColumn...`) also retain the original columns of the dataset? There are 5 cols in the original dataset, and I want to add 3 more (for a total of 8). Or does you solution *change* the schema to only have 3 columns in it (dropping the original 5)?

Comment: It will also retain the columns, you have to explicitly call drop to drop specific columns

Answer (score 0):

To create a new column you can use withColumn. And if you already have a function, you need to register that function as an UDF (User Defined Function)

```
val sd = sqlContext.udf.register("deriveSpecialDate",deriveSpecialDate _ )
val su = sqlContext.udf.register("deriveSpecialUuid",deriveSpecialUuid _ )
val sp = sqlContext.udf.register("deriveSpecialPhrase", deriveSpecialPhrase _)
```

To use this udf you need withcolumn which creates a new column as

```
ds.withColumn("special_date", sd($"moniker))
 .withColumn("special_uuid", su($"moniker))
 .withColumn("special_phrase", sp($"moniker))
```

With this you get your original dataset with three new added columns.